# What does implication operation reflect for?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to know what does implication operation reflect for?

*The truth table for the implication operator:*
[image]

```
using System;
class Implication
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool p = false, q = false;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0) p = true;
                if (i == 1) p = false;
                if (j == 0) q = true;
                if (j == 1) q = false;
                Console.WriteLine("p is " + p + ", q is " + q);
                if (!p | q) Console.WriteLine(p + " implies " + q +
                 " is " + true);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I mean why we use Implicatin Operation?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You may want to reword the question.

Comment: the result is false or false => false if you use ||

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"p implies q" means "if p is true, then q must also be true":

```
p       q       p implies q
false   false   true
false   true    true
true    false   false
true    true    true
```

You can check that `!p | q` has the same truth table.

Comment: And most notably, it is *not* an equivalence (“*Q* is true if, and only if, *P* is true”) which means that if *P* is false *Q* can be anything. It's surprising how many people don't get that difference.